# 'CalucateNumbers' is missing exception specification 'noexcept'

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner with C++

I'm having a trouble when I set the header class values.

```
CalucateNumbers::CalucateNumbers() {
    ResetValues();
}

void CalucateNumbers::ResetValues() {
    firstNumber = 0;
    secondNumber = 8;
}
```

`CalucateNumber` is missing exception specification `noexcept`

Help please?

This is the C plus plus Code file with the name `FBullCowGame.cpp`

```
#include "FBullCowGame.hpp"

FBullCowGame::FBullCowGame() {
    Reset();
}

void FBullCowGame::Reset() {
    CurrentTries = 0;
    MaxTries = 8;
}
```

This is the header file with the name `FBullCowGame.hpp`

```
#ifndef FBullCowGame_hpp
#define FBullCowGame_hpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

#endif /* FBullCowGame_hpp */


class FBullCowGame {
public:
    void Reset(); // TODO Make a reset void
// Not important.., The important is this ^^
private:
    int CurrentTries;
    int MaxTries;
};
```

[Here is the MCVE on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/rYor9A).

Comment: Does the definition match the header?

Comment: Yes it does....

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] then

Comment: Well, yes, it's true that they do not have a `noexcept` specifier. Is that a message from the compiler?

Comment: @PeteBecker yes its from the compiler "XCODE"

Comment: @drescherjm I have edited the question check it now please. :)

Comment: I mean the header for `CalucateNumbers` since the bug is likely there. `FBullCowGame` does not seem to be related.

Comment: @drescherjm i edited it to FBullCowGame

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You were incorrect when you said "Yes it does" when asked whether the definition matches the header. It does not match the header, because it's not even present in the header!

Your `class FBullCowGame` doesn't declare a custom constructor, so the compiler created a default one. You then try to create a custom one, and the compiler thinks you're trying to implement the default constructor (which happens to be `noexcept`), so it says "This redeclaration doesn't match the implicit declaration."

Your real problem is that you forgot to tell the compiler "I'm going to give this class a custom constructor."

```
class FBullCowGame {
public:
    FBullCowGame(); // <----- you forgot this
    void Reset(); // TODO Make a reset void
// Not important.., The important is this ^^
private:
    int CurrentTries;
    int MaxTries;
};
```

(You also have a problem with the scope of the `#ifdef` guard in your header file.)

Comment: Thank you so much, Actually i don't know what does #ifdef means, because its with the default file

Answer (score 6):

That's a very misleading error message. The problem is that the class definition does not declare a default constructor, but the source code attempts to implement one. To fix this, add a declaration for the default constructor to the class definition.